# best way append named array to array in PHP 5.2

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.2

I got used to this notation for creating empty arrays and add named elements to them when needed;

```
$array = [];

// in case there is an error
$array["error"][] = "new error message as element 0 of $array['error']";
```

Now I learned that the [] notation for arrays does not work in older versions of PHP, like PHP 5.2.

Instead I have to do;

```
$array = array(
  "error" => array()
);

array_push($array["error"], "new error message as element 0 of $array['error']");
```

This way is a little bit inconvenient in my case because the great thing about the first code snippet is that the "error" entry in `$array` is only created when there is an actual error, whereas in the latter case the entry (although empty) exists either way.

Is there a way to get similar 'functionality' (i.e. specifying/adding named elements when needed, not at initialisation) in a way that is also easily readable in PHP 5.2?

Comment: "Now I learned that the [] notation for arrays does not work in older versions of PHP, like PHP 5.2." not correct

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its base assertion is incorrect

Comment: hm, I ran into problems with [] in 5.2 and found this entry that made sense to me http://stackoverflow.com/a/5966855/3097469

Comment: @grueb You might be confusing `$array = []`, which declares an array and is not supported in older versions of php with `$array[] = $something`, which appends an element to the array and is supported in all versions of php

Comment: The [short array syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) (`$array = []`) was introduced on PHP 5.4

Comment: @ FuzzyTree, yes sorry – that was a just a pasting error – that is exactly what I used ... corrected it in the post. Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**
The first code snippet in the original post was reading `$array = array[];`. The author corrected it after I posted this answer.

---

The first code snipped is incorrect. There is no such thing as `array[]`. The correct syntax is `array()`.

```
$array = array();

// in case there is an error
$array["error"][] = "new error message as element 0 of $array['error']";
```

You don't have to worry about PHP versions. This syntax always worked on PHP since its dawn and it will probably work forever. Keep using it.

Comment: great, thank you! I had `$array = [];` in my original code ... but got confused / made a pasting error (corrected it in the original post) ... but now I understand that this was the problem and not `$array["error"][] = ...`. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

The first way of creating `array` in `PHP` is incorrect. This syntax works in `PHP5.2` below too, so you dont need to worry about it.  You don't need to use `array_push` and simply do following.

The correct syntax is:

```
$array = array(); // notice it doesn't to array[]

// add error when there is one
$array["error"][] = "new error message as element 0 of $array['error']";
```